# Strange symbols in Eclipse editor window

Tags: eclipse, editor, whitespace, line-endings

There are some symbols in my Eclipse editor. I don't know what what they are or how to remove them.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image. The relevant text should be entered directory to the question body.

Comment: @Eran While in most cases it is wrong to post screenshots, this is a case where the problem can't be described otherwise.

Comment: @ashu Why? Can't those symbols be copied and pasted too?

Comment: @Eran I think to OP is confused about the whitespace markers.

Comment: @Eran: Looks like tab and line-end hinting provided by the IDE so no..?!

Comment: @sudelicious I wonder what happens if you untoggle "¶" symbol from the toolbar.

Comment: Those are 'whitespace markers' see the duplicate for more details

Comment: @Eran The Eclipse whitespace markers won't look like this in plain text, so an image is appropriate here.

Comment: @Eran An image often shows important information that the questioner is not aware of (such as versions of the tools used, etc.). Due to "please don't post code as image" comments, images were removed, making the question unanswerable. If you don't want to do OCR yourself, please ask for the code as text in addition. And by the way, it is better to tell someone what to do instead of what not to do.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show Whitespace characters

[image]